# Swift Use array in Json

Tags: arrays, json, swift

When I add an array in my JSON object and convert it to JSON, after printing there is parenthesis instead of curly brace.

```
var jsonObject : [String: Any] = [:]

var x = [1,2,3,4]
jsonObject["arr"] = x
do{
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [])

    let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
    print(decoded)
} ...
```

And the result of printing:

```
{
arr = (
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
     );
}
```

But in JSON, to show an array it uses [ instead of (.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the dictionary(!) to JSON and then you **convert it back** and print it.

To print the JSON string you have to write

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
print(jsonString ?? "Wrong data")
```

Comment: Thanks. After doing this and printing the result is "{\"arr\":[1,2,3,4]}".  Is it OK? Some added backslashes are OK?

Comment: This is OK. The backslashes are virtual, they are needed to display double quotes in a literal string.

Answer (score 1):

When you print a Swift object, Swift debugger is free to print it however it wants. It's just for convenience, there are no guarantees about the format. So, it prints arrays in parenthesis.

When you convert it to JSON, on the other hand, it creates a JSON string, and JSON has a specified format for arrays, which includes square brackets.

**UPDATE:** after reading the question again, it seems to me you're under the impression that you're printing a JSON representation of your object. You're not. What you do currently is you convert your Swift object to JSON, and then convert it back to a Swift object. And then you print the resulting Swift object (see paragraph 1 of my answer).

So, if your goal is to print the JSON representation, you need to convert jsonData to String (see other answers), and print that string. You shouldn't use `NSJSONSerialization` again for backward conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this to print your JSON.

```
public extension Collection {

    /// Convert self to JSON String.
    /// - Returns: Returns the JSON as String or empty string if error while parsing.
    func json() -> String {
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: [.prettyPrinted])
            guard let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                print("Error creating string with data.")
                return "{}"
            }
            return jsonString
        } catch let parseError {
            print("json serialization error: \(parseError)")
            return "{}"
        }
    }
}
```

The conversion is correct, It's just that you are printing decoded version, which is swift dictionary, not JSON.

```
var jsonObject : [String: Any] = [:]

var x = [1,2,3,4]
jsonObject["arr"] = x
print(jsonObject.json())
do{
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [])

    let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
    print(decoded)
}
```

Output:-

```
{
  "arr" : [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some print clauses to you code, and pasted the console log as comments.

```
var jsonObject : [String: Any] = [:]

var x = [1,2,3,4]
jsonObject["arr"] = x
print(type(of: jsonObject)) // Dictionary<String, Any>
do{
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted)

    let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments)
    print(type(of: decoded)) // __NSSingleEntryDictionaryI

    let str = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
    print(str!) /* {
    "arr" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
         ]
    }*/
}
```

As you can see, the type of `decoded` is `__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI`, so its result of printing is not as what you expected, with "(" instead of "[". If you want the right representation in JSON, you should convert the `jsonData` to `String`.